# Don't show na values in R with ggplot package

Tags: r, ggplot2

I plotted that graph in R with ggplot. In the excel file column there is so much NA. For this plot, how can I do not show NA values (Gray ones)?

```
ggplot(dolu, aes(x=month, y=year, color=value)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:12, labels=c("Ocak", "Şubat", "Mart", "Nisan", "Mayıs", "Haziran", "Temmuz", "Ağustos", "Eylül", "Ekim", "Kasım", "Aralık")) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(x="Ay", y="Yıl")
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to set the color used for the `NA` values to `"transparent"` in `scale_color_continuous` .

Using some fake random example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

dolu <- data.frame(
  month = rep(1:12, each = 21),
  year = 2000:2020,
  value = sample(c(1:6, NA), 21 * 12, replace = TRUE)
)

ggplot(dolu, aes(x = month, y = year, color = value)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = 1:12,
    labels = c("Ocak", "Şubat", "Mart", "Nisan", "Mayıs", "Haziran", "Temmuz", "Ağustos", "Eylül", "Ekim", "Kasım", "Aralık")
  ) +
  scale_color_continuous(na.value = "transparent") +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(x = "Ay", y = "Yıl")
```

[image]

And a second option would of course be to simply to drop the observations with missing `value`s:

```
ggplot(subset(dolu, !is.na(value)), aes(x = month, y = year, color = value)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = 1:12,
    labels = c("Ocak", "Şubat", "Mart", "Nisan", "Mayıs", "Haziran", "Temmuz", "Ağustos", "Eylül", "Ekim", "Kasım", "Aralık")
  ) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(x = "Ay", y = "Yıl")
```

Comment: It worked, thank you Sir! If you mind, how can I show all years as label? and changing legend up to its value as point?

Comment: You could do `scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1990:2020)`. A second option would be to convert your `year` variable to a factor or a character. And for the legend: Convert your `value` to a factor, i.e. `ggplot(dolu, aes(x = month, y = year, color = factor(value)))`

Comment: ... but in that case we have to switch to `scale_color_discrete` instead of `scale_color_continuous`.

Comment: Aaand they worked sir, thanks a lot again! Have a good evening. ✌